# Set cover image while record audio in android

Tags: android, audio

Hello I am recording audio using `MediaRecorder` and save it in *MP4* format. and upload to the server. as well record video as MP4 using camera and upload to server.
So while I am receive my uploaded item from server as uploaded url list. and I am playing all it in `VideoView`. video and audio play good. now here is the thing while I am playing video it's display video frame on video view but while playing audio it's black.  basically audio and video file extension are MP4 so I can't make different while adding it in to `VideoView` other wise I'll add imageview and display some default image and hide VideoView.
so is there any way to record audio with cover image so while I am playing it in Video view so it display that cover image...
I know that using ffmpeg we can do this but I got lots of error while compiling it in my windows pc. so is there any way to add cover image while record audio with pure android api? sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I google everything but I can't find any solution for convert audio file to video file with using image. So I have to go with `FFMPEG`.

So I add [WritingMinds java FFMPEG](https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java) in my project using gradle dependency. Then convert MP4 audio with cover image into the MP4 video.

There are some limitation in this precompile library. like it not work in android 24 and some commands like `-speed`, `cpu-used`, `-deadline` which are most important for all the operation(But still we can perform other operation). there are some disadvantage also like slow speed, and some features which required for specific operation are not include in the compile library. (So I gave advice to compile your own ffmpeg library for android project in linux or mac pc(windowns have lots of issues)).

I hope this will help someone who's this type of scenario :)